# How to change Logon Hours for AD user by c#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to update Logon hours for AD user by c#.

User logon time is:

> - Mon -> Friday: 7AM to 7PM
> - Sat: 7AM to 1PM
> - Sunday: not login

I folow this article:
https://anlai.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/active-directory-permitted-logon-times-with-c-net-3-5-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/

Below is my code, but time not set true

```
DirectoryEntry user = ad.GetUser("nguyen.abc");
            //////////////////////////
            var newTest = new List<TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime>();
            var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Monday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 17, 30, 0), zone));
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 17, 30, 0), zone));
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 17, 30, 0), zone));
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Thursday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 17, 30, 0), zone));
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Friday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 17, 30, 0), zone));
            newTest.Add(new TestCRUD_AD.LogonTime(DayOfWeek.Saturday, new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0), new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0), zone));

            var newResult = PermittedLogonTimes.GetByteMask(newTest);
            //var hoursResult = PermittedLogonTimes.GetLogonTimes(newResult);
            user.Properties["logonHours"].Add(newResult);
            user.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: You need to show your efforts in order to be helped by us :)

Comment: sorry, i updated question